# How do I build a webpage for printing so it won't split badly over pages?

Tags: printing, page-break

I have a web application that generates a long report and I need to print it. If I just print the page it will break at the end of the physical page. How can I calculate where to make a break in the web page so that the page breaks line up with the physical pages when they print?

Answer (score 8):

We have a system which prints out invoices for selected orders which places a

```
<br style="page-break-before:always;">
```

between each invoice. This means each invoice goes on a new page.

It's also good practice to use a print stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

which can hide/display relevant areas of the page. No point printing out leftnav links etc when someone wants the actual page contents.

Answer (score 6):

- [Paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html)
- [Print Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_ref_print.asp)

  - [page-break-after](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_print_pageba.asp) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-after))
  - [page-break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_print_pagebb.asp) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-before))
  - [page-break-inside](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_print_pagebi.asp) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-inside))

Comment: nice one. it even works in IE 6-8 -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Those pages are outdated; they claim that these styles only work in Opera, when this is no longer the case. [I tend to avoid W3Schools.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @BrianKoser I tend to avoid it anymore as well. But, 3 years is long enough for an opinion of something to have been slightly different. And, W3Fools has only [existed for about a year](https://twitter.com/#!/kangax/status/23541759497740291). Still, you have a point, so added MDN links.

Answer (score 2):

I usually avoid web page (HTML) printing all together. If formatted printing is required, I generate PDF or CSV/Spreadsheet formats for my customers to print in any way they want.

I usually generate print for global use, meaning that all types of settings differ (eg. paper size: Legal, Letter, A4, etc) from workplace to workplace. I've found it to be too big a task to guarantee esthetic output everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is a css property to attempt to ensure the position of page-breaks.  You can give an element the rule `page-break-before: always` or page-break-after: always` to indicate whether the break should be before or after the element.  This has pretty poor support across browsers and I wouldn't rely on it.  See http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_print_pageba.asp for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Either with CSS [`page-break-before/after`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_ref_print.asp)

Other ways:

- use [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?group_id=102) and load the data in a report, instead of a html page
- use [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) with XSL to translate your HTML (or the raw data) to FOP and later to PDF

Both methods are quite extensive, so if you don't want to spend some effort better directly skip to another answer....